# How to delete entire row using php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, delete-row

I am making an application where user can register and login using their email and password. User can have their own profile like name, address, etc. I also created DELETE BUTTTON so that user can delete their whole account.
I want user to tap that DELETE BUTTON and it ask for their email and password to delete their whole account?*Below is the code to delete but this just delete what is written in the code, I want to ask individual user to enter thier email and password to delete only their own ROW.*

```
<?php
$servername = "host";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=13";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

[Here in picture one user having user id 13 want to delete his account (entire row)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBAR8.png)

Comment: Please add your code, how you're connecting to database, more details

Comment: @Sakuto: Thanks, the question is now edited.

Comment: `delete from users where user_id = 13`

Comment: What's the question? Surely you're not expecting someone to write this for you. Please read the rules.

Comment: Have you actually read anything on  SQL in PHP?

Comment: @aron9forever: I am sorry, I did many research but could not found the actual possibilities I want so, I have edited the question.

Comment: @jsfan: I am sorry, I did many research but could not found the actual possibilities I want so, I have edited the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There a DELETE Statement in SQL, by using which you can delete the whole row very easily, for example, in your case the query will look like, as

```
DELETE from table_name
WHERE email=xyz;
```

This will completely remove the data of a account having the email equals to xyz, you can replace table_name and xyz with those your own. Then the query will work as you expected.
For more information on how to use DELETE Statement you can visit [SQL DELETE Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp)

**Note :** You can also use the User_ID instead of email in where clause, then it will filter the results based on user_id, but make sure that is unique otherwise all row having those User_IDs or emails will be deleted

Comment: I want button to ask user's email and password to confirm so that, it deletes just the individual's entire row.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should leave `mysql_*` and start using `PDO` or `mysqli` (since mysql_* is deprecated and now removed in the new version).

Your desired request is just `DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=13`, you just need to put a form and execute the query only if the fetched data is equals to the one the user filled.

Comment: I want button to ask user's email and password to confirm so that, it deletes the individual's entire row.

Comment: Please keep in mind that we're not a coding service. Write your current code and where you're stuck

Comment: OK but help is help, I am beginner so I am asking for solution. If I knew things then I would not be here. no offence, I think anyone can ask freely here :)

Answer (score -1):

When the user taps the delete button, show an html/php form for email and password confirmation. I imagine that the email is the key information for your users, so when that form is submitted, get the email input in a variable: $email_variable for example do this in sql: 
"DELETE FROM tablename WHERE email='".$email_variable."'"

Comment: You are teaching how one makes scripts vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: this guy doesn't yet know how to make an sql query, so we must teach him the basics first.